# Ошибка при повторной покупке монет

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchases

У меня имеется список с разными количествами монет. Типа этого:

```
------------------------
10 монет         10руб.
------------------------
20 монет         20руб.
------------------------
30 монет         30руб.
------------------------
```

И это в диалоговом окне, то есть `DialogFragment`.

У меня не покупается, и при повторной попытке купить, выскакивает ошибка:

> IabResult: Unable to buy item (response: 7:Item Already Owned)

**Код**:

в `onCreateView` вызываю `setupBilling()`

```
private void setupBilling() {
        mHelper = new IabHelper(getActivity(), CheckoutApplication.getPublicKey());
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                            result);

                    try {
                        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
                    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

При клике на пункт `ListView` вызываю метод `buyCoins(String ProductID)`, с параметром ID продукта:

```
private void buyCoins(String name) {
        PRODUCT_NAME = name;

        try {
            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(), PRODUCT_NAME, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener);
        } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

И остальные методы `Хелпера`:

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "error in mPurchaseFinishedListener: " + result);
            } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(PRODUCT_NAME)) {
                try {
                    mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);

                } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    };

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "error in mReceivedInventoryListener: " + result);
            } else {

                for (CoinsPriceModel coinsPriceModel : coinsPriceModelList){
                    PRODUCT_NAME = coinsPriceModel.getName();

                    Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(PRODUCT_NAME);

                    try {
                        mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
                    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    };

    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {

            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                ToastUtils.shortToast(getActivity(), "SUCCESS in mConsumeFinishedListener");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "error in mConsumeFinishedListener: " + result);
            }
        }
    };
```

Мучаюсь уже 2-й день. Погуглил, ни один вариант мне не помог. ЗЫ: Первый раз сталкиваюсь с `IAB`

Вопрос: Что я делаю не правильно, как исправить, подскажите???

Comment: Получается что вы однажды купили продукт, а потребление его не прошло/не было сделано. Можно сделать проверку на вашу ошибку и в случае её возникновения сначала потребить продукт, а потом его запустить на покупку.

Comment: Не совсем понял. А как сделать проверку на ошибку?

Comment: Собственно эту ошибку вы и получаете: `IabResult: Unable to buy item (response: 7:Item Already Owned)`

Comment: Т.е. надо что то типа (за имена полей не отвечаю, этот апи не юзал (IABHelper)) `if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "error in mPurchaseFinishedListener: " + result); if(result.responseCode==7){/*ТУТ надо потребить покупку, раз она не потреблена и заново запустить процесс покупки*/}
            }`

Comment: А каким API вы пользовались?

Comment: А хз. Просто взял гугловую доку и пилил.

Comment: Понятно. Попробую...

Comment: Оно точно сработает. Вам только надо узнать конкретные имена полей и методов для получения кода ошибки.